# Access of Undefined Property "loader"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'm working on a project in flash, and recently decided that I wanted to switch my test file to become the main class inside my project. The file is called ColorClass.as, and the associated .fla file is ColorClass.fla. They are located in the same directory, and the Document class of ColorClass.fla is ColorClass. I am using a loader inside ColorClass.as to load an external SWF as follows:

```
public var loader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(loader);   //adding loader
loader.load(new URLRequest("../Resource/flash/WheelClasses.swf"));  
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,wheelsLoaded);
```

I am trying to create a test file, color_Test.as (and an associated color_Test.fla) that loads ColorClass.swf and gets the class definition to be used in the test file.

However, when I try and compile ColorClass.as/.fla and create a .swf file, I am receiving multiple instances of

```
Access of undefined property loader.
```

and

```
Call to a possibly undefined method addChild.
```

These errors are occurring completely independent of color_Test. Am I going about something the wrong way here? I'm just trying to compile ColorClass.as/.fla, which I could do so before trying to change it to become another class.

Answer (score 1):

In an AS3 class, all functional code needs to be contained in a function.

So, aside from the first line (which is a variable declaration), the rest are just floating in the class not wrapped in a function:

```
public var loader:Loader = new Loader();  //THIS LINE IS FINE

//THESE THREE LINES NEED TO LIVE IN A FUNCTION
addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("../Resource/flash/WheelClasses.swf"));  
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,wheelsLoaded);
```

If you want the code above to execute right away, place it in the [constructor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000178.html) function (the function whose name matches the name of the class).

```
public function ColorClass {
    addChild(loader);   //adding loader
    loader.load(new URLRequest("../Resource/flash/WheelClasses.swf"));  
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,wheelsLoaded); 
}
```

Comment: Please make your answer more useful to future readers by explaining better what the solution is.    Show how you changed the code at the very least.

Comment: I did it myself this time (basically hijacking your answer).  Please take note of how I explain why the problem exists, and I offer a solution or alternative.  I also link to references that may help someone understand better.  This is a good formula for writing good ansers

Comment: Thank you for this. I had a really long day when I asked the question, and about 5 minutes after I asked I looked at the code and saw how silly of an error I was making.